# python: get next item while in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, subprocess

Currently I'm using subprocess to read data from a catalina log file:

```
text = subprocess.popen(" cat filename.txt",shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

The text format will have groups of lines in the following format:

```
INFO timestamp | Inbound Message
ID: 1234
Address: http://www.google.com
```

What I'd like to do is something along the lines of:

```
for line in text.stdout.readlines():
    if line.split()[line.count(' ')-2] == "Inbound":
        time = "%s %s"%(line.split()[1],re.sub(',','.',line.split()[2]))
        id = text.stdout.readline().split()[1]
        address = text.stdout.readline().split[1]
```

However, this functionality doesn't seem to work, as the readline() does not pull the next line in text.

Comment: so you want the line after Inbound or just all ID and Address pairings? Also why are you using cat to open and read a file?

Comment: (Very) useless use of cat]? ... What's wrong with `open('filename.txt', 'r').readlines()`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you've called `readlines()`, to read all of stdout until the very end into a big list to loop over it. So, when you call `stdout.readline()` again, it returns nothing, because you're already read everything.

The answer here is to not use `readlines()` and iterate over the file directly:*

```
for line in text.stdout:
```

Now, each time through the loop, `text.stdout`'s file pointer is pointing right after the current line, so `text.stdout.readline()` will give you the next line (and consume it, so it won't show up the next time through the loop).

It might be more readable to use `next(text.stdout)` here, because that makes it clearer that you're using the same iterator as the `for` loop, but it will have the same effect either way.

That being said, trying to consume an iterator from inside a loop that's also consuming it is a very good way to confuse yourself. You may want to consider stepping back a level and asking whether there's a clearer way to solve this problem.

---

<sub>* In fact, "don't use `readlines()`" is almost *always* the answer, or at least a useful improvement, to any code involving `readlines()`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Don't use subprocess to get the contents of a file use `open` then iterate over the file object  calling next on the file object to get to the two lines after the line containing `Inbound`:

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "| Inbound" in line:
            time = line.split()[1] # split Inbound line
            id = next(f).split()[1]  # split following line with id
            address = next(f).split()[1] # split next line containing address
            print(time,id,address)
('timestamp', '1234', 'http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('filename.txt') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        if line.endswith(' | Inbound Message\n'):
            timestamp = line.split()[1]
            ident = next(lines).split()[1]
            address = next(lines).split()[1]
            print timestamp, ident, address
```